# New records get an autogenerated id value. How to get 0 as a new id as in ExtJs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, upgrade, extjs6, extjs-stores

In ExtJs 4, a new record in a store got `0` as an id, before it is synced to the server. In ExtJs 6, the id `'Mb.model.images.Image-1'`.

```
Ext.define('Mb.model.images.Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'code', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'filename', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'path', type: 'string'}
    ]
})
```

Is it possible to get the old behavior in ExtJs 6 ?

I looked at `identifier: 'sequential'`, but this assigns an autoincrementing id on the client side, which will collide with the server-side assigned id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. The changes in **ExtJS 5** around sessions requires all models to have a unique `ID`.

You can use the `phantom` property to see if the model has not ever been saved.

Furthermore, the Proxy class knows if the model is a phantom, and will issue different calls to the server depending on if the status of the phantom flag (Create operations vs Update operations).

Any server-side assigned `ID` will then override the `ID` of a freshly saved model.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. This then means two things : 1 on the server I have to disregard those client side ids, and 2 when I display the id of the record in the database in a grid, I hide those meaningless auto-generated id strings.

Comment: Pretty much. Though on the 1st point, you can customise your proxy to ensure the Create operation doesn't send the ID if you can't make your backend understand the difference between a Create and an Update.

Comment: That is an interesting point. Can you tell how to configure the proxy to not send the auto-generated id?

Comment: Not off the top of my head; worst case would be you need to subclass it or apply an override.